# How to hide subcategory titles in category blog and only display the subcategory descriptions

Tags: joomla-3.x, category-blog, subcategories

I have the newest Joomla version. I have created a Category Blog with a link from the homepage menu. And want to achieve something like this on the page:

### What I have now:

Subcategory title

Subcategory description

Subcategory title

Subcategory description

Subcategory title

subcategory description

---

I have linked each subcategory description image and direct to a blog of articles. I want to hide the subcategory titles, but couldn't find the option in the "Menus". There is only option to choose show or hide "Subcategory description" but no option to show or hide subcategory title.

### What I want to achieve:

Subcategory description

Subcategory description

Subcategory description

How to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to override the category blog layout template.

Copy all the code from:

```
/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_children.php
```

and paste into a new file you'll create at:

```
/templates/<your active template>/html/com_content/category/blog_children.php
```

This will result in Joomla using that new file instead of the original one you copied from. Now modify the code in your new file to make it work the way you want.